# MSBuild 17: how to generate a temporary folder name

Tags: msbuild

I have an MSBuild project target which needs to create a zip file from a folder (lets call it FolderA) of files, some of which files need to be excluded and not added to the zip file, so the target needs to copy the files (except for the excluded files) from FolderA to a temporary folder, then call the target ZipDirectory target on the temp folder.

I'm creating the temp folder by creating an itemgroup

```
<ItemGroup>
       <TempStagingFolder Include="$([System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()))" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

but this never evaluates to a folder name, just the static method calls on `System.IO.Path`

How can I create a temp random folder name in MSBuild to pass to the ZipDirectory target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
        <ItemGroup>
            <TempStagingFolder Include="$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()), $([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())))" />
        </ItemGroup>
```

Each static property method call needs to be enclosed in `$()`.

For troubleshooting, maintenance, and for overriding you may find it useful to build up the folder path and name from properties, e.g.:

```
        <PropertyGroup>
            <TempStagingPath Condition="'$(TempStagingPath)' == ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())</TempStagingPath>
            <TempStagingFolderName Condition="'$(TempStagingFolderName)' == ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())</TempStagingFolderName>
            <TempStagingFolder Condition="'$(TempStagingFolder)' == ''">$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(TempStagingPath), $(TempStagingFolderName)))</TempStagingFolder>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
            <TempStagingFolder Include="$(TempStagingFolder)" />
        </ItemGroup>
```

Property names and Item names do not collide. `$(TempStagingFolder)` and `@(TempStagingFolder)` are different 'objects'.

By having separate properties, if there is an issue you can check the specific property. Testing that the property is not already set, allows for overriding the property with a different value.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Dodds, I did in fact figure it out myself and was going to answer it myself, but you beat me to it. As a fairly recent newcomer to MSBuild, I didn’t realise that property and item names don’t collide, that’s very useful to know.